# GO-OpenGL LoadMatrixd and GetDoublev issue

Tags: opengl, go

```
gl.MatrixMode(gl.MODELVIEW)
gl.PushMatrix()

m := new([16]float64)
setIdentity(m)

gl.LoadMatrixd((*gl.GLdouble)(&m[0]))
gl.Rotated(90, 0, 1, 0)
gl.GetDoublev(gl.MODELVIEW_MATRIX, (*gl.GLdouble)(&m[0]))
gl.PopMatrix()

fmt.Printf("%f", m[0])
// m[0] == forward.x
```

The contents of m doesn't not change after the GetDoublev. I am trying to port some C code (which works and it basically this). What am I doing wrong?

The C code as requested:

```
//m is float[16] set to identity
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();

glLoadMatrixf(m);
glRotatef(90, 0,1,0);
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Can you post the C code?

Comment: Does `m := new([16]float64)` initialize the array to 0, or is it uninitialized at that point?

Comment: Whoops, I am setting the matrix to identity before I call LoadMatrixd

Comment: @Jim Buck new() initializes to the zero value, however, I don't think it's correctly used in the code above

Comment: What is setIdentity() and what if the output of fmt.Println(m)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call sdl.SetVideoMode() before you can use Matrix functions.